# UIScrollView is not smooth while scrolling two UITableViews simultaneously?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I made TWO UITABLEVIEWs like below

[image]

Here one Table is UITableViewLeft, and Second is UITableViewRight?

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview_newsFeed;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewMainNewsFeed;
```

I properly synthesized them and connected to xib.

For scrolling both UITableViews simultaneously, I wrote code as below

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {


    NSLog(@"contentOf Set of ui scrol view");


    UIScrollView *otherScrollView = (scrollView == self.leftTableView) ? self.rightTableView : self.leftTableView;

    [otherScrollView setContentOffset:[scrollView contentOffset] animated:YES];
   }
```

Everything is working fine, but its not smooth.

I tried to make threat, and I also used below block

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.003f
                     animations:^{

                     } ];
```

But no user.

How can I smoothly scroll both TableViews at the same time.

Thanks

Comment: what's your views hierarchy first

Comment: i'd first try with [otherScrollView setContentOffset:[scrollView contentOffset] animated:NO]; But if you want a good solution, try with ONE UICollectionView

Comment: What's the implementation of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: Try to implement Images in background thread instead of main thread.

Comment: There is nothing in CellForRowAtIndexPath, except user of CustomCell.

Comment: Mr. Devangi, there is no Image Loading anywhere, so Please read Question before suggestion.

Comment: Sir, If you check height, there is light difference at the end, so If I use UICollectionView, I think I cannot get this GOAL. @nomannasim

Comment: Of course you can reach your goal with UICollectionView.... You even should. Did you try just to set the content offset without animation as I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you are scrolling the tableview it is executing the method. So no need to fire the method just **setContentSize** of the scrollview from the maximum tableview length among the two.
Maintain a int variable by calculating the height of tableview and in last tableview cell enter the **scrollView.frame = tableView1.frame;** or **scrollView.frame = tableView2.frame;**

Comment: but where should I use setContentSize and how?

Comment: There is no ScrollView Gentleman, Read my question again. I think you are not getting my point. 

Where is your ScrolLView, a new OBJECT?
Or what is it?

Comment: Hey mate add a scrollView and make the two tableview as subview, Make the tableview scrollEnable = FALSE; and then you would be able to scroll the scrollview with two subview as tableview. I think this is something you should try. Also set the content size of scrollview to the height of tableview

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe not the only one solution but have you tried to make opaque all your view in cells too ? I red that it could provoque performance issues.